# Kendo ui MVVM using Icenium

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, kendo-ui, icenium

I am starting to develop a cross platform app using  Kendo UI and Icenium to which I am totally new  , I am trying to get this example to work in a new project to,inorder to get used to data-binding and MVVM in this new environment , so I started a new kendo ui mobile app which has multiple views and a big collection of functionalities . what am I trying to do is to get this simple example to run inside icenium  ..
    (Javascript)

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
name: "John Doe",
displayGreeting: function() {
    var name = this.get("name");
    alert("Hello, " + name + "!!!");
}
});
kendo.bind($("#view"), viewModel);
```

HTML

```
<div id="view" data-role="view">
<input data-bind="value: name" />
<button data-bind="click: displayGreeting">Display Greeting</button>
</div>
```

the example runs perfect on jsfiddle.net ,

I don't get the structure of the app and the data that exists at app.js and where should I initialize the view model .

Comment: "where should I initialize the ...." what?!

Comment: sorry .. I corrected the post ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a mobile application, you don't need to call kendo.bind..., you just need to create the kendo.mobile.Application, and then define which model your view will be bound to by adding data-model="viewModel".

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { platform: 'ios' });

<div id="view" data-role="view" data-model="viewModel">...</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/UGoSute/1/edit

Comment: Thank you giltnerj0 , that was really helpful , have a nice day :)